Redis keys are not showing after a certain period

I am trying to create StatefulSet for redis in a k8s cluster where I
will send streams, create hash values etc. I was checking some
configurations for the last 4/5 days. I am facing issues related to
redis because it is creating backup strings (backup1, backup2,
backup3, and backup4) after a certain period and I can't access
the old keys. I am sharing the configurations. This is observed by
redis insight. How can I access all the data by not losing it
to backup strings? Or I am not sure if it is in the backup strings
or not.

apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: StatefulSet
metadata:
  name: test-redis
spec:
  serviceName: "test-redis"
  replicas: 1  
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: test-redis  
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: test-redis  
    spec:
      terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 10
      containers:
      - name: test-redis
        image: redis:7.4  
        args: ["--requirepass", "admin", "--appendonly", "yes", "--save", "900", "1", "--save", "30", "2",
              "--appendfsync", "everysec", "--stop-writes-on-bgsave-error", "no"]

        resources:
          limits:
            cpu: 100m
            memory: 512Mi
        ports:
        - containerPort: 6379
          name: redis
        volumeMounts:
        - name: redis-data
          mountPath: /data  


  volumeClaimTemplates:
  - metadata:
      name: redis-data
    spec:
      accessModes: [ "ReadWriteOnce" ]
      storageClassName: "pd-standard-retain"
      resources:
        requests:
          storage: 20Gi
---
apiVersion: storage.k8s.io/v1
kind: StorageClass
metadata:
  name: pd-standard-retain  
  annotations:
    storageclass.kubernetes.io/is-default-class: "false"
provisioner: kubernetes.io/gce-pd
parameters:
  type: pd-standard  
allowVolumeExpansion: true
reclaimPolicy: Retain  
volumeBindingMode: Immediate



adding the link of the solution:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50264694/my-redis-auto-generated-keys
